# Blank page in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I have a large Sitecore site which is working with almost no issues, but there is one particular page which renders as blank. No menus or layout and no errors. No errors are recorded in the database.

When I preview that same page through the CMS, no problem.

The page has been published, as has its layout and template.

Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Comment: Did you try checking in the web database directly to make sure those items have *actually* been published? From the Sitecore Desktop, switch to web db by clicking the icon in the bottom right and selecting it. The check in the content tree, including the presentation and template.

Comment: thanks jammykam, good debugging tips but as you can see below I ended up discovering I had different problem altogether!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is a bit embarrassing - actually there is a directory under my website with the same name as the page I am browsing to. Of course IIS doesn't pass the request on to Sitecore, it just says "hey I found that resource" and in my case, returns a blank page.

I would have expected a directory listing or an error message in this case, but a blank page is what I get.

Nothing to do with Sitecore, but it could affect anyone working with a CMS.

(PS this is a pre existing site I've recently started working on).